# What does $\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}$ equals to in circular motion?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I know that $\vec{v}=wr\hat{\theta}$ in uniform circular motion. This equation looks like a result of a cross product.

Yesterday, I started to learn *Basic Dynamics of Rigid Bodies*. My teacher wrote $\vec{v}=\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}$ in the lecture. But I have never seen this. This equation also equals to $\vec{v}={\omega}{r}\sin(\vec{\omega},\vec{r})\hat{?}$ If $\sin(\vec{\omega},\vec{r})$ equals to $\sin(\pi/2)$ then the equation equals to $\vec{v}={\omega}{r}\hat{?}$

I wonder that how the unit vector $\hat{?}$ is equal to $\hat{\theta}$. When I try to figure it out, I can't. Can you explain it, please?

Comment: A2A @ACuriousMind

Comment: what does  ̂ mean in your first formula, since the formula of your teacher is the usual one. the next equations apply only to the  absolut value of v not to the vector .

Comment: @trula Sorry, I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first equation works when you have already isolated the plane of rotation.  It treats $\omega$ as a scalar.  Sometimes we can't isolate it into a 2d case like this, such as if there are angular accelerations or other considerations.  To handle the full 3d case, we define rotation using a vector, $\vec{\omega}$.  This vector is defined to have a magnitude equal to the $\omega$ from the first equation, and a direction which is is at right angles to the rotation.

Now, if you're a purist, that cross product might bug you.  In these cases, we're not actually using the cross product of two vectors, but the product of a *bivector*, which is easier to trace down to why it is the correct tool to use.  It just so happens that in 3 dimensions, the math for cross products and bivectors is identical, and historically we've found teaching cross products easier than introducing bivectors.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, sir. Does the magnitude of rotation vector $\vec{\omega}$ equals to angular velocity $\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}$?

Comment: @ICCQBE Yes, it will.  In fact, if you take a simple rotation in the x-y plane, where $\vec\omega$ is in the z direction, and crunch the numbers for the cross product, you'll end up with the 2d equations you are used to.  It's a good simple test case to see how the cross product works its magic.

Comment: Alright! Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean bivector in the geometric/clifford algebra sense?

Comment: Oh, no. I didn't mean it. I just heard it first time. Thanks.

Comment: @roshoka [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector#Rotation_vector).

Comment: I'm a little confused by that then. I know that angular momentum can be a bivector, and since $\vec{L} = I \vec{\omega}$, then you can conclude that $\vec{\omega}$ is a bivector. But wouldn't $\vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$ then imply that $\vec{v}$ is a trivector?

Comment: @roshoka Ah.  I think I see where I'm not quite right.  Rotation is accomplished with a Rotor and uses $RxR^\dagger$ to do the rotation.  Rotation rate, which is what we're talking about with $\omega$ would be the first derivative of that.

Answer (score 1):

you can write any  vector with his magnitude and unity direction

$$\vec{v}=|\vec{v}|\,\vec{n}\tag 1$$

with

$|\vec{v}|=|\vec{\omega}|\,|\vec{r}|\,\sin(\theta) $

where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{\omega}$ and $\vec{r}$

thus equation (1)

$$\vec{v}=|\vec{\omega}|\,|\vec{r}|\,\sin(\theta)\,\vec{n}$$

where the vector n is perpendicular to the vector omega  and r

$\vec{n}\perp\vec{\omega}\quad ,\vec{n}\perp\vec{r}$ with $||\vec{n}||=1$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.